# Substituting items in a list and performing mathematical operations on the new items

Tags: list, math, replace, operation

I have a large dataset list that is in the following format:

```
mylist = list(5)
for (i in 1:5)
{mylist[[i]] <- sample(sampler,10)}
mylist
```

I want to use these numbers as an index for another set of data in a vector, eg

```
substitutes <- 1:100
```

I want to substitute list items by the appropriate substutes values, eg. put substitutes[3]  anywhere the index 3 appears in mylist. Then I want to perform various arithmetic functions such as "sum" on the group of values in each element in the resulting list to yield a new vector. The data set is huge, so it has to go quickly. And I am a novice and totally stuck!

I tried replace() in various configurations, without success.

Comment: what programming language is it?

Comment: Oops, sampler <- sample(1:100)

Comment: This is the R language, sorry!